Autowired emailService Inteface returns null but only when called internally (requests from outside don't run into this issue)
I have a simple notification server that I'm working on and I have an EmailService interface and an EmailServiceImpl class. The main application class calls an EmailingWorker class, which contains a method that uses an Autowire EmailService to send out an email.
The problem is that when attempting to call on this method internally, I get a Cannot invoke "com.FMNNotificationServer.FMNNotificationServer.messaging.emailing.EmailService.sendSimpleEmail(com.FMNNotificationServer.FMNNotificationServer.models.EmailDetails)" because "this.emailService" is null message.
However, if I hit the API that I've created for that same method I can successfully send an email.
I suspect that Spring is simply not picking up on the emailService bean despite my best efforts to make it visible.
Here is the main class (you can see the commented out @ComponentScan that I used trying to help Spring locate the EmailService bean):
@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan({"com.FMNNotificationServer.FMNNotificationServer.messaging.emailing"})
public class FmnNotificationServerApplication {



    @Autowired
     EmailService emailService;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FmnNotificationServerApplication.class, args);

        MessageDetails messageDetails = new MessageDetails();
        messageDetails.setRecipientEmail("<email_address_here>@gmail.com");
        messageDetails.setMessageSubject("Buongiorno");
        messageDetails.setMessageBody("Here is  a test of the emailing component");
        messageDetails.setAttachment("");
        //EmailService emailService1 = new EmailServiceImpl();
        //EmailingWorker emailingWorker = new EmailingWorker(emailService1);
        EmailingWorker emailingWorker = new EmailingWorker(messageDetails);
        //emailingWorker.setDetails(messageDetails);
        emailingWorker.sendSimpleEmail(emailingWorker.getEmailDetails());

    }

}

That class uses the EmailingWorker class:
@Data
@RestController
public class EmailingWorker {

    @Autowired
     EmailService emailService;
    private EmailDetails emailDetails;

    public EmailingWorker(){
        this.emailDetails = new EmailDetails();
    }



    public EmailingWorker(MessageDetails messageDetails){
        this.emailDetails = new EmailDetails();
        this.emailDetails.setSubject(messageDetails.getMessageSubject());
        this.emailDetails.setMessageBody(messageDetails.getMessageBody());
        this.emailDetails.setRecipient(messageDetails.getRecipientEmail());
       // this.emailDetails.setAttachment(messageDetails.getAttachment());
    }

    public void setMessageDetails(MessageDetails messageDetails){
        this.emailDetails = new EmailDetails();
        this.emailDetails.setSubject(messageDetails.getMessageSubject());
        this.emailDetails.setMessageBody(messageDetails.getMessageBody());
        this.emailDetails.setRecipient(messageDetails.getRecipientEmail());
    }

    public void setDetails(MessageDetails messageDetails){
        this.emailDetails = new EmailDetails();
        this.emailDetails.setSubject(messageDetails.getMessageSubject());
        this.emailDetails.setMessageBody(messageDetails.getMessageBody());
        this.emailDetails.setRecipient(messageDetails.getRecipientEmail());
    }


    @PostMapping("/sendMail")
    public String sendSimpleEmail(@RequestBody EmailDetails emailDetails){
        this.emailDetails = emailDetails;
        String status = emailService.sendSimpleEmail(emailDetails);
        System.out.println("Emailing status: " + status);
        return status;
    }
}

Here's the simple interface that's autowired in the EmailingWorker class:
@Service
public interface EmailService {
    String sendSimpleEmail(EmailDetails emailDetails);

}

Here's the EmailService class implemented:
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService{

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.username")
    private String sender;

    public EmailServiceImpl(){

    }

    public String sendSimpleEmail(EmailDetails details){
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setFrom(sender);
            mailMessage.setTo(details.getRecipient());
            mailMessage.setText(details.getMessageBody());
            mailMessage.setSubject(details.getSubject());

            javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
            return "Email successfully sent...";
        } catch (Exception e){
            return "Error while sending email. Exeception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public String sendSimpleEmailTwo(EmailDetails details){
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setFrom(sender);
            mailMessage.setTo(details.getRecipient());
            mailMessage.setText(details.getMessageBody());
            mailMessage.setSubject(details.getSubject());
            System.out.println("message details here: " + mailMessage.getText());
            JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
            javaMailSender.setPort(587);
            javaMailSender.setUsername("<email_goes_here>@gmail.com");
            javaMailSender.setPassword("<password_here>");
            javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
            return "Email successfully sent...";
        } catch (Exception e){
            return "Error while sending email. Exeception: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}

